# NHibernate with NLog or Log4Net or something else?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, log4net, nlog

I want to use NHibernate in my project, and it comes with log4net by default.

In my opinion, it would be a wiser choice to go for Nlog as it still gets updates, log4net on the other hand is completely outdated.

Is there a best choice because I don't really believe in using outdated technologies in my application. On the other hand, it's the one being delivered in the package of nhibernate...

recommendations would be welcome!

*** replace outdated with 'nolonger-updated'**

Comment: "outdated", "believe"... those are not objective terms to refer to software. log4net is still the standard and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not say that log4net is outdated. Software does not [rust](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html). Log4net is rather mature and though there are things that could be improved it certainly does its job. If you have any problem with log4net you can always fix it yourself. I would go for log4net as NHibernate uses log4net. Having two log frameworks does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 8):

In Nhibernate 3 dependency on log4net is broken. I would suggest you using recently [released beta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/) and combine it with NLog.

Comment: is this a good stable version to start from? cause it hasn't been mentioned yet on http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx

Comment: it seams to be stable http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/        just you see only Release versions there, not bettas

Comment: for a private project I wouldn't care that much, but in this case, as I'm working for a customer, I'm not so keen about working with unreleased versions...

Comment: Well... Its open source. Your project is also not released and that doesn't mean that customers cant use it. :) Nhibernate has a bunch of unit tests and if betta is available then they are all pass. So it should be as stable as previous versions

Answer (score 0):

You do know that NHibernate does not require usage of Log4Net for it's logging, right? There is an interface that you can implement and configure NHibernate to use as an alternative.